# Array along a path

Tags: modifiers

I always get distortions when using the curve modifier.

I am uploating the blend file.

**[image]**

Can someone explain to me what I am donig wrong and how to position the array along a curve correctly.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you move your object where it belongs to (to its origin) like this in edit mode:

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the origin of each object (mesh and path) to its geometry (right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*), put the object at the same location as the path with the help of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* then *Selection to Cursor*), in the object *Array* modifier, set the *Constant Offset* on X to 0, in the object *Curve* modifier, set the *Deform Axis* on -Y, move the object in the scene until it is the way you want.